# "Object is possibly 'undefined'." in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The code below throws `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` at `obj.field1 += ',' + v;`. TypeScript says the `obj` may be undefined, but the `obj` can not be undefined at this point because `{field1: 'testtest'}` is assigned in case `map.get(key)` returns undefined.

Why I got this error? How can I fix this?

```
interface TestIF {
  field1: string;
}

export class MyClass {
  test(): void {
    const map1: Map<string, TestIF> = new Map();
    const map2: Map<string, string> = new Map();

    const key = 'mapkey';
    let obj = map1.get(key);
    if (obj == null) {
      obj = {field1: 'testtest'};
      map1.set(key, obj);
    }

    map2.forEach( v => {
      obj.field1 += ',' + v;  // Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of TypeScript are you compiling against and what does your tsconfig.json (or equivalent command line call) look like?  I ask because TypeScript's flow analysis, especially of null/undefined types has changed a lot over the last ~2 yrs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error happens because control flow analysis is difficult (see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)), especially when the information you want to keep track of cannot be represented in the type system.

In the general case, the compiler really cannot figure out much about what happens when functions accept callbacks that mutate variables.  The control flow inside such functions is a complete mystery; maybe the callback will be called immediately and exactly once.  Maybe the callback will never be called.  Maybe the callback will be called a million times.  Or maybe it will be called asynchronously, far in the future.  Since the general case is so hopeless, the compiler doesn't even really try.  It uses some heuristics which work for a lot of cases, and which also necessarily fail for a lot of cases.
You picked one of the failures.

The heuristic used here is that inside of a callback, all narrowings which occurred in the wider scope are reset.  That does reasonable things for code like this:

```
// who knows when this actually calls its callback?
declare function mysteryCallbackCaller(cb: () => void): void;

let a: string | undefined = "hey";
mysteryCallbackCaller(() => a.charAt(0)); // error!  a may be undefined
a = undefined;
```

The compiler doesn't know when or if `() => a.charAt(0)` gets invoked.  If it gets invoked immediately when `mysteryCallbackCaller()` is called, then `a` will be defined.  But if it gets called sometime later, `a` may be undefined.  Since the compiler cannot guarantee safety here, it reports an error.

---

So what can we do to address this issue in your case?  There are two main solutions I can think of.  One is to just tell the compiler that it's wrong and that you are sure that `obj` will be defined.  This can be done using the [`!` non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-):

```
map2.forEach(v => {
  obj!.field1 += "," + v; // okay now
});
```

This works with no compile time error.  The caveat to this solution is that the responsibility for ensuring `obj` is defined is now only yours and not the compiler's. If you change the preceding code and `obj` truly is possibly undefined, then the type assertion will still suppress the error, and you'll have issues at runtime.

---

The other solution is to change what you're doing so that the compiler *can* verify that your callback is safe.  The easiest way to do that is to use a new variable:

```
// over here the compiler knows obj is defined
const constObj = obj; // type is inferred as TestIF
map2.forEach(v => {
  constObj.field1 += "," + v; // okay, constObj is TestIF, so this works
});
```

All I've done here is assign `obj` to `constObj`.  But at the time this assignment takes place, `obj` cannot be `undefined`.  Thus `constObj` is just a `TestIF`, and not a `TestIF | undefined`.  And since `constObj` is never reassigned and cannot be `undefined`, the rest of the code works.

---

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEHcAsHtQawHbXAZwpApg0AXSBLNAQwGMcBXIgGyoE9QTqq18c1GaAjUuAfgCgAJhhJUiAJwygAZuQRl80bAFtaKHBnG0Awk24k4umpoAUJTgC5QJgJSgAvAD5QAN2j5BNq248BufvxUGDigRFbq4vgIAOagAD6gcsLSURiCDqAARJi0mf6q6po6ejxGQeImtg7ORAB0JJASAII4JgAMNja+oCCgmuLQ4gCEoKGgykT0nFJJGCkIafxEGbPzaf78URri0qRSACoY6gCSAGKgAN78oykYVIIAjOE4kTH+AL4BGAAeAA6DIVERBQaAAsjoxCDLtdcEdWl5XO50ldRqMSEp1OMiL8nqBQdiADwRKLRAA0oEOJ1OznsoAW4Dx2Ns-lRDAxIQmvwATFZ8b8iS8SeTiTEaXSMAy+cyAqz0QhMXAMPRaZlOYrcizUUEQtBOAArDKch61aLBEzqrow0b4aTWXUG+y0hDkGh2FGs0D2jIXGT4O6PKyZDTqYM4TKgd6a1lG2ooM3q8n2y2sz5WrHc2rSQYAUVIkBMLmq0I9nv1Q0zfvuD1AAGoVaTwzXXN1etA4JM6cg0+9LWnWy5NKBMJJcJg2cpfvhyvAkKhSwbCKBkqlBGm5Zj1zgAPL6jL2ltgHC0X5SRdRaT9NKhNCUnBnNOcrmZnN5gtF92y9k7vUV-3VutZA2tbNj0YBtpM5Kbt+oCLreZzCrAeCLuAgxwCg3bJhG-CfEAA)

Comment: would be useful to be able to instruct typescript that the value inside the inner scope follows a synchronous flow, instead of total suppression with `!` that defeats typing protection.

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering with the same problem now, and the solution to me was (adapted to your case):

```
if (!obj) {
   return ( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Map's `get` method is defined as `Map<string, TestIF>.get(key: string): TestIF | undefined`, so when you set `obj`, it's type is `TestIF | undefined`.

When you (re-set) `obj`'s type inside the `if` block, it's in a different scope. When you read `obj` inside the `forEach`,  it's also in another scope. The TypeScript compiler is unable to establish the correct type in the changed scopes.

Consider this (working) code:

```js
    const key = 'mapkey';
    let obj: TestIF; // Create variable with a Type
    if (map1.has(key)) { // We know (with certainty) that obj exists!
      obj = map1.get(key) as TestIF; // We use 'as' because we know it can't be Undefined
    } else {
      obj = { field1: 'testtest' };
      map1.set(key, obj);
    }
```

Even though Map.get() will always return `V | undefined`, when we used `as`, we forced TypeScript to treat is as `V`. I use `as` with caution, but in this case we know it exists as we have called  `Map.has()` to check it's existence.

Also, I want to stress that `(obj === undefined)` is much better than `(obj == null)`, which just checks for falsyness. [[more info]](https://codeburst.io/javascript-null-vs-undefined-20f955215a2)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `forEach()` function accepts a callback that can mutate `obj` (i.e. you could do `obj = null;` inside the loop). For this reason Typescript cannot assume that `obj` is not null.

An easy solution is to use a `for...of` loop instead, which doesn't required a callback:

```
for (const v of map2) {
  obj.field1 += "," + v;
}
```

I personally try to use modern language alternatives that do not use callbacks when possible precisely because it really helps with Typescript type inference. Some examples that come to mind:

- Use `for...of` instead of `forEach(callback)`.
- Use `[... ] (spread syntax)` instead of `map(callback)`.