# Typescript say variable can be null even if I check before

Tags: typescript

I have an argument that can be `string` or `null`. At the beginning of the function I check to see if this argument is null, if yes, I set a default value.

However, after this check, typescript tells me that this argument can still be null.

Here is an example

```js
pollUrl: function (
    httpClient,
    url: string,
    maxIterations: number | null = null,
    delay = 600
  ): Promise<any> {
    if (maxIterations == null) {
      maxIterations = 25
    }
    return httpClient.get(url).then((result) => {
      return Utils.delay(delay).then(() => Utils.pollUrl(httpClient, url, maxIterations - 1, delay))
    })
  },
```

in the `Utils.pollUrl` at the end of the function, typescript is telling me `maxIterations: Object is possibly 'null'.`, even if I check before

Comment: I don't see an actual question here.  You're talking about a behavior you don't like.  Which of the following is your primary question:  "why is this happening?" or "how can I change my code to prevent this from happening?"

Comment: Also, please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wR59XW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385552/object-is-possibly-undefined-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

What about instead using a default similar to what you have with `delay`:

```
pollUrl: function (
    httpClient,
    url: string,
    maxIterations = 25,
    delay = 600
  ): Promise<any> {
    return httpClient.get(url).then((result) => {
      return Utils.delay(delay).then(() => Utils.pollUrl(httpClient, url, maxIterations - 1, delay))
    })
  },
```

Can use like:

```
pollUrl(client, 'foo', undefined, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks this solution work effectively in this case but it does not explain why typescript does not know that `maxIteration` is not null after my if statement. Should I use a guard instead to check it is not null?

Comment: Sure, you can still check for null as null will not cause the default to kick in, but TypeScript will complain if you try to pass null to `pollUrl` for that argument with this signature. This allows to pass `undefined`, which will default to `25`.